# How to count the length of a nonzero sequence in SAS

Tags: sas

I'd like to count the length of the non zero sequence in a data as below:

```
ID  Value  
1     0  
1     0  
1     2.5  
1     3  
1     0  
1     4  
1     2  
1     5  
1     0
```

So here the length of the first non zero sequence is 2 and the length of the second non zero sequence is 3. The new data will look like this:

```
ID  Value  Length  
1     0    0  
1     0    0  
1     2.5  2   
1     3    2  
1     0    0  
1     4    3  
1     2    3  
1     5    3   
1     0    0
```

How can I write SAS code to accomplish this task with a large data like this. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to store each of the lengths?  What is your desired output?  A new dataset with a variable representing these lengths (down the column), or something else?

Comment: Yes. I need to store the length in a new variable. I edited my question as above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution.  It assumes there are no missing values in the Value variable and that your ID variable does not have any significance for this problem.

```
*creates new length variable that starts at 1 and increments by 1 from start to end of every non-zero sequence;
data step_one (drop=prev_val);
   set orig_data;
   retain prev_val length 0;
   indx = _n_;
   if value ne 0 and prev_val ne 0 then length = length + 1;
   else if value ne 0 then length = 1;
   else if value = 0 then length = 0;
   prev_val = value;
run;

*sorts dataset in reverse order;
proc sort data=step_one;
   by descending indx;
run;

*creates modified length variable that carries maximum length value for each sequence down to all observations included in that sequence;
data step_two (drop=length prev_length rename=(length_new=length));
   set step_one;
   retain length_new prev_length 0;
   if length = 0 then length_new = 0;
   else if length ne 0 and prev_length = 0 then
      length_new = length;
   prev_length = length;
run;

*re-sorts dataset back to its original order and outputs final dataset with just the needed variables;
proc sort data=step_two out=final_result (keep=ID value length);
   by indx;
run;
```